# Google Apps Script - How can I get the name of the sheet I am deleting with onChange trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I fire the trigger onChange when I delete a sheet. With this trigger I would like to run a script that would get the name of the sheet I am deleting, search this name in a range of cells in another sheet and clear the matching cell.

I actually can do all of this expect retreiving the name of the sheet I am deleting.

Here is the script I have for the moment :

```
    function removeMonthSheetFromList1(){
          ScriptApp.newTrigger('removeMonthSheetFromList2')
          .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
          .onChange()
          .create();
    }

    function removeMonthSheetFromList2(e){
        if (e.changeType = 'REMOVE_GRID') {
          removeMonthSheetFromList(e);
        }
    }

    function removeMonthSheetFromList(e){
      var ssVariable = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Feuille 15');
      var firstRow = 4;
      var column = 13;
      var deletedSheetName = e.getSheetName();
      var foundIndex = ssVariable.getRange(firstRow, column, ssVariable.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(deletedSheetName).findNext().offset(0, 1).getRowIndex();
      var cellToDelete = ssVariable.getRange(foundIndex, column);
      cellToDelete.clear();
    }
```

e.getSheetName() doesn't give me the name of the sheet I'm deleting, but the sheet's name where I land after having deleted my sheet. How can I get the name of the sheet I am deleting ?

Comment: AFAIK events objects don't have methods: `var deletedSheetName = e.getSheetName();`

Comment: Try Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

Comment: Like Cooper mentioned, the event object doesn't have methods, it returns only the following [information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#:~:text=amin%40example.com-,Change,-(installable)) maybe a workaround would be to retrieve the sheet names and compare if with the list in the other Sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following flow?

1. When the Spreadsheet is opened, the current sheet names are retrieved and stored in PropertiesService.
2. When one of the sheets is deleted, the deleted sheet name is retrieved by comparing the initial sheet names and the current sheet names.
3. `removeMonthSheetFromList` is run by giving the deleted sheet name.

When this flow is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, please reopen the Spreadsheet. By this, `onOpen` is run and the initial sheet names are stored in PropertiesService.

In this modification, it supposes that your function `removeMonthSheetFromList2` is installed as the OnChange trigger. Please be careful about this.

```js
// Added
function storeSheets_({ source }, p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()) {
  var sheets = source.getSheets().map(f => f.getSheetName());
  p.setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(sheets));
}

// Added
function onOpen(e) {
  storeSheets_(e);
}

// Modified
function removeMonthSheetFromList2(e) {
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (e.changeType = 'REMOVE_GRID') {
    var currentSheets = e.source.getSheets().map(f => f.getSheetName());
    var sheets = JSON.parse(p.getProperty("sheets"));
    var removedSheet = sheets.find(f => !currentSheets.includes(f));
    if (removedSheet) {
      removeMonthSheetFromList(removedSheet);
    }
    storeSheets_(e, p);
  } else if (e.changeTyle == "INSERT_GRID") {
    storeSheets_(e, p);
  }
}

// Modified
function removeMonthSheetFromList(removedSheet) {
  var ssVariable = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Feuille 15');
  var firstRow = 4;
  var column = 13;
  var deletedSheetName = removedSheet;
  var foundIndex = ssVariable.getRange(firstRow, column, ssVariable.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1).createTextFinder(deletedSheetName).findNext();
  if (!foundIndex) return;
  foundIndex.clear();
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I'm trying to add something to your code. I would like to refresh the list "sheets" when I press a button that insert a new sheet, by adding the name of the new sheet to the list "sheets".

I've tried to use the function storeSheets_ in the function my button is calling, but I have an error "Cannot destructure property 'source' of 'undefined' as it is undefined." on the call of the function storeSheets_. How can I resolve this error and refresh "sheets" script property ?

Comment: @Magicrevette About your new question, I would like to support you. But the question of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Alright, thank your patience. Here is the new question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76022268/google-apps-script-source-getsheets-return-error-source-undefined-when-it-is)