# Google Apps Script - source.getSheets return error 'source undefined' when it is called from script triggered by a button on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to store the names of my spreadsheet's sheets in a script property with the onOpen trigger (I succeed here), then when I want to modify this same scrpit property by adding a new sheet name in it when I press a button on Google Sheet (I fail here).

Here is my script :

```
function onOpen(e) {
  storeSheets_(e);
}

function storeSheets_({ source }, p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()) {
  var sheets = source.getSheets().map(f => f.getSheetName());
  p.setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(sheets));
}

function onButton(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheetName = "myNewSheet";
  ss.insertSheet(newSheetName, 1);
  storeSheets_(e);
}
```

I assigned the function onButton to a button on my sheet. When I press it, a new sheet called myNewSheet is created, but I get this error :
"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'source' of 'undefined' as it is undefined."

Can I send an event object on a function assigned to a button ? Why is it undefined here ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, when a button assigned `onButton` is clicked, `e` of `onButton(e)` is not given. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue. And, it seems that only `source` is used at`storeSheets_`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function onButton(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheetName = "myNewSheet";
  ss.insertSheet(newSheetName, 1);
  storeSheets_(e);
}
```

#### To:

```
function onButton() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheetName = "myNewSheet";
  ss.insertSheet(newSheetName, 1);
  storeSheets_({ source: ss });
}
```

- By this modification, `source` is given by `storeSheets_({ source: ss })`. And, when `onButton()` is run, at `storeSheets_`, all sheet names including `myNewSheet` are stored in PropertiesService.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you, it has solved my problem !